# MySQL - querying same table twice

Tags: php, mysql

I have a fully working query, however, I don't know how to read the results in PHP.

```
SELECT * FROM [...]
LEFT JOIN media ON m_media_id=r_release_media_id
[...]
LEFT JOIN media AS episode_media ON episode_media.m_media_id=ms_media_id
```

Here's the thing: I'm calling the "media" table twice, as you can see. It reads out great as a SQL query, but I get media.m_media_id and episode_media.m_media_id - how do I get those in PHP?

I'm calling the query like this, however the $record-> part doesn't work as the dot messes it up. How do I do this correctly?

```
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
while ($record = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $1 = $record->media.m_media_id 
    $2 = $record->episode_media.m_media_id
}
```

I've searched to find the answer but I can only find the MySQL queries, not the PHP part. Thanks.

Comment: Don't `SELECT *` in a join query.  Always be specific about the columns you need and alias them `SELECT media.m_media_id AS media_id, episode_media.m_media_id AS episode_media_id`.  In PHP, access the aliased columns as `$record->episode_media_id`

Comment: ... Also mysql library is deprecated, Use PDO or mysqli

Comment: For your information, you can't use `$1` nor `$2` (a numeric value directly following the `$`) ([here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) is the manual that explain how variables are named).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use aliases.

I suggest querying like this:

```
SELECT media.m_media_id as name1, episode_media.m_media_id as name2....
```

Then you should be able to call them as:

```
$name1 = $record->name1
$name2 = $record->name2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, saved me lots of time. :)